# issue is that the objects are not initializing the default date

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Date{
    
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    static Date defaultDate;
    bool leapYear(int) const;
    public:
        
        Date(int d = 0 , int m = 0 , int y = 0); // constructor with defualt parameters
        ~Date();
        
        static void setDefaultDate(int d , int m  , int y );
        void setDay(int);
        void setMonth(int);
        void setYear(int);
        void addDays(int);
        void addMonths(int);
        void addYears(int);
        
        int getDay() const;
        int getMonth() const;
        int getYear() const;
};

Date Date::defaultDate(12,13,14);

int main(){
    
    Date d1(29 , 2 , 2000) , d2;    
    d1.addDays(478);
    cout<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"YEAR = "<<d1.getYear()<<endl;
    cout<<"MONTH = "<<d1.getMonth()<<endl;
    cout<<"DAY = "<<d1.getDay()<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    
    cout<<"YEAR = "<<d2.getYear()<<endl;
    cout<<"MONTH = "<<d2.getMonth()<<endl;
    cout<<"DAY = "<<d2.getDay()<<endl;
    
    

 }



Date::Date(int d , int m , int y){
    
        
    if(y == 0){
        
        this->year = defaultDate.year;
        cout<<"default year = "<<year<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"year "<<y<<endl;
        setYear(y);
    }
    
    if(m == 0){
        
        this->month = defaultDate.month;
        cout<<"default month = "<<month<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"month "<<m<<endl;
        setMonth(m);
    }

    if( d == 0 ){

        this->day = defaultDate.day;
        cout<<"default day = "<<day<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"date "<<d<<endl;
        setDay(d);
    }
}

Date::~Date(){
}

bool Date::leapYear(int ly) const{
    
    if( (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0) ){
        
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

void Date::setDefaultDate(int d , int m , int y){
    
    defaultDate.setDay(d);
    defaultDate.setMonth(m);
    defaultDate.setYear(y);
}

void Date::setYear(int y){

    if(year > 0){
        
        year = y;
    }   
}

void Date::setMonth(int m){
    
    if(m > 0 && m <= 12){
        month = m;
    }
}

void Date::setDay(int d){
    
    int daysInMonths[12] = {31 , 28 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 30 , 31};
    
    if(leapYear(year)){
        
        daysInMonths[1] = 29;
    }
    
    if(d > 0 && d <= daysInMonths[month-1]){
        
        day = d;
    }
}

void Date::addDays(int ad){
    
    int daysInMonths[12] = {31 , 28 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 31 , 30 , 31 , 30 , 31};
    
    if(leapYear(year)){
        
        daysInMonths[1] = 29;
    }
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= ad ; i++){
        
        day++;

        if(day > daysInMonths[month-1]){
            day = 1;
            month++;            
        }
        if(month > 12){
            month = 1;
            addYears(1);
        }
    }
}

void Date::addMonths(int am){
    
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= am ; i++){
        
        month ++;
        
        if(month > 12){
            month = 1;
            addYears(1);
        } 
    }
}

void Date::addYears(int ay){
    
    year += ay;

    if(month == 2 && day == 29 && !leapYear(year)){
        
        month = 3;
        day = 1;
    }
}

int Date::getDay() const{
    
    return day;
}

int Date::getMonth() const{
    
    return month;
}

int Date::getYear() const{
    
    return year;
}
```

Comment: You get access out of bounds in `if(d > 0 && d <= daysInMonths[month-1]){` when `month` is `0`. [Use address sanitizer](https://godbolt.org/z/9rYqY4Mvr)

Comment: So in which line of main do you have an issue?

Comment: Why do you think there's a problem?  What output do you see?  You initialize the static member `defaultDate` with `Date Date::defaultDate(12,13,14);` which doesn't make much sense: the month value of 13 will be ignored by `Date::setMonth`.

Comment: yeah i know that the month is out of scope but also if i change the month , the year is also not initializing with default year